# How to address column names with spaces in oracle, when the query is already inside double quotes?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a query like this, which is already in double quotes.

```
result = db.Query("SELECT ACTUAL_N_WELLS, TARGET_N_WELLS, YTD ACTUAL AS YTD_ACTUAL, 
YTD BUDGET AS YTD_BUDGET, (CONVERT(DATETIME,PERIOD,112)) AS DATES 
FROM DASH_GL_DRILLING_PERF
 WHERE ASSET_NAME='Bab & Gas Asset' 
AND (  to_date(DASH_GL_DRILLING_PERF.PERIOD,'yyyy/mm/dd') > 
(SELECT add_months(max(to_date(DASH_GL_DRILLING_PERF.PERIOD,'yyyy/mm/dd')),-3) 
from DASH_GL_DRILLING_PERF))");
```

In this the column "YTD ACTUAL" and "YTD BUDGET" have spaces, but since the query is already inside double quotes, how do I write the column names? How can I escape the double quotes in this case?

Comment: This is not a SQL question. The question is "How do I escape quotes in programming language X.". Please tell us what X is.

Comment: This is not an Oracle or sql question. Escape the double quotes in the language you are using to query the database.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: The language is C#, but when I was using SQLServer, using [] like [YTD ACTUAL] worked fine, but the same thing in oracle is not working, thats the reason I put it up as an Oracle question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `C#`, `Java` or `PHP` on this, escape the double quotes with backslash `\`

```
result = db.Query("SELECT ACTUAL_N_WELLS, TARGET_N_WELLS, \"YTD ACTUAL\" AS YTD_ACTUAL....");
```

Comment: that worked sir, thank you! I thought this was an Oracle question as it worked properly with SQLServer.